Can't access Numpy
I'm trying to run a code on VSCodium (new to Python) but it says that numpy module is not found, but when trying to install it says the requirement is already satisfied!
I read multiple threads about this and could not get anything to solve this issue!
I have been trying to fix this for multiple hours now so any help/tips is very appreciated!


you are using the wrong python interpreter. you have anaconda installed, so use the python provided by anaconda, which should be in ~/anaconda/bin/python

I changed the enviroment in VSCodium but getting another error now, ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

I would suggest you start clean. Check how anaconda environments work and set up a conda environment. Then in that environtment install all the libraries you need. Or you can decide not to use anaconda at all and use virtualenv instead.

If you look in the bottom right of your IDE (VSCodium) you can see that the code is running in 3.9.6, but your terminal call is using python 3.12 from a conda environment.
If you want to use the conda env, you can change that in the bottom right (click where it says python 3.9.6) and selecting the env that you want, ideally the one that matches your terminal call.
you can verify that you are in the right python by typing: python --version

If you have already installed it, make sure it’s installed in the correct environment.

Errors like this happen a lot. It's probably because you may have installed it in another version of Python in the same virtual environment, or in another environment.
No matter why, to fix this you can try creating a new virtual environment using Command ⌘ + Shift ⇧ + P if you're on a Mac or Ctrl + Shift + P if you're on windows and selecting Python: Create Environment…, venv or conda, then the version of Python you have installed that you would like to use.
Then change your Python version to the corresponding version you selected for your virtual environment on the bottom right corner (the button that says 3.9.6 64-bit or something similar).
Once you have done this, you should be able to install numpy again in the current environment by using pip install numpy if you are using venv environment and conda install numpy if you are using conda environment.
